# Symfony2 Automatically HTTP Cache Clearing

Tags: symfony, caching

**Hi All**

Recently we migrated to symfony2 application. Now I am having a problem with storage on the systems. The system is running on the docker container. It looks like application is not deleting the http_cache automatically. After searching in the internet found few following solutions. But not sure about the actual problem.

**Solution 1**

```
// app/AppCache.php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class AppCache extends HttpCache
{

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'default_ttl' => 500,
        // ...
        );
    }
}
```

This looks like a solution, but not really able to test it on local system.

**Solution 2**

Periodically run following command via cron job or similar to clear the cache.

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

**Hints**

I am getting following error on the server, but it is not too often. I am not sure if it is the real issue that is causing system to crash.

```
[xx-xxx-xxxx xx:xx:xx] WARNING: [pool www] child 2452 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/sessions) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php on line 93"
```

**Server Setup**

The application is running on docker container.

Any help or hint would be great,am I missing anything?

Comment: Take a look at ```Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\Store``` it handles the storing and invalidating of cacheable response objects. There is no built-in way to handle your requirement, but I think after looking at that class you should able to find a way on how to automatically clean up invalidated/purgeable objects.

Comment: @MichaelHirschler thank you very much. That was a useful information. It looks like application is having ownership of the directory but not the 0777 access rights. So when there is stale content detection, It will lock the request, write the cache and unlink the stale content, hence it has no 0777, thus store object never created. And there will not be unlink called. Thus it keeps on writing the files and never deletes them.